# Detectar cuando se deje de escribir en input con Angular 14

Tags: angular

Requiero de su ayuda con respecto a Angular 14, estoy iniciando en este medio y tengo un problema el cual describo a continuacion.

**Requiero que al momento que un usuario escriba en un input, el sistema sea capas de detectar cuando se finaliza de escribir, espera un intervalo de 1 segundo y realiza una peticion al backend.**

Estoy usando la KeyDown para detectar los cambios de informacion en el input. pero el sistema me repite el resultado las veces que se a tipeado en el campo.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ced" name="ced" #txtCed placeholder="C&eacute;dula o Rif - Ej: 12345678 o J-1234567-8" (keydown)="cedEvent($event)">
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-client',
  templateUrl: './info-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info-client.component.css']
})
export class InfoClientComponent implements OnInit {
  values = '';
  
  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
    
    cedEvent(event: any){
      let timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(event.value);
        console.log(event.target.value);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      },2500);     
    } 
  
  }
```

Si escribo un numero de 8 digitos en teoria me haria 8 veces la peticion al servidor y solo deseo que se realice 1 sola vez.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda prestada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes arreglar haciendo `timeout` una variable de instancia y limpiándola antes de ejecutar el siguiente `setTimeout`

```
export class InfoClientComponent implements OnInit {
  values = '';
  timeout: any;
  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
    
    cedEvent(event: any){
      if(this.timeout != null){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
       }
      this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(event.value);
        console.log(event.target.value);
      },2500);     
    } 
  
  }
```

Comment: Perfecto... es lo que queria funciona de maravilla muchisimas gracias